# Multiline comments in http

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client

I am using REST Client in VSCode. The file extension is `http`.

Where we can comment using hash: `#`, double slash: `//` and separate requests with tripple hashes: `###`.

But how can we have multiline comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply like how we do in `html` extension:

```
<!--
Multi Line Comments
Goes here
-->
```

Ah, we also need to be tricky here. Otherwise, sending request will cause issue. Use tripple hashes before and after multi line comments. Though, it lets us see "Send Request". That's why it's tricky:

```
###
<!--
Multi Line Comments
Goes here
-->
###
```

Thus, multiline comment is only fit between the requests but not inside the request. I'm still looking for better way to do it.